# 2560x1440 resolution not available on 2560x1600 laptop

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

I have never had this resolution available (I have an AMD Ryzen 7 5800h on Lenovo Ideapad 5 Pro 16") neither can I create a custom resolution on AMD Radeon / Adrenalin Edition settings like I have seen other solutions provide. A 'Display' tab also does not show up in NVIDIA Control Panel.

I can provide any information required, I have the latest drivers and everything, I've checked.

Comment: The resolution you want is very close to native. So why not just use native

Comment: My reasoning for this is for screen recording purposes, as the 16:9 layout is much more appealing to the eye than black bars and a resized window for the 16:10 layout. To make 1080p video I have to change resolution to 1920x1080 but the 1440p is available, just not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to confirm the AMD Radeon tool doesn't have a custom resolutions option under the display tab?

That would be the best way to do set a custom resolution.
But since you've said it doesn't I'm going to trust you and recomend that use [CRU](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU)

This should allow you co create a custom resolution with the settings you need. It's usually used for "overclocking" the refresh on panels known to work at higher refresh rates but it will also allow you to override the resolutions on monitors, and is usually used when you have a monitor with faulty EDID values.

Depending on how your panel handles this different resolution, you are either going to get black bands or a weird looking stretched image.

But hopefully this works for you. Enjoy!

Comment: This worked well enough, I had to fiddle with the refresh rate settings as it hated 60hz and I had to default it to 120hz for some reason, but from what I can tell it works perfectly.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if you can thanks!